# Javascript Asynchronous Methods Changing the State of Models they don't belong to

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, backbone.js, scope

I have two different models that are doing asynchronous work but I don't know why they're changing eachothers state? I'm at a total loss. Please help.

I have an object that has a method which waits for some time, and then pushes the value of it's property member plus one to the array in it's result member and then resolves it's state but as you can see in the output that the second promise resolves a state with both values.

I was hoping someone could explain to me what is happening or offer a correction.

```
var Model = backbone.Model.extend({
    "initialize": function() {},
    "defaults": {
        "Property": undefined,
        "Result": []
    },
    "method": function( Input ) {
        var xModel = this;
        return new rsvp.Promise(function( resolve ) {
            xWait( Input ).then(function() {
                //This is the line which is changing the behavior in question.
                xModel.get("Result").push( xModel.get("Property") + 1 );
                resolve( xModel );
            });
        });
    }
});

var xModel1 = new Model({
    "Property": 0
});

var xModel2 = new Model({
    "Property": 1
});

xModel1.method( 5 ).then(function( Result ) {
    log( "Result: " + JSON.stringify( Result ));
});

xModel2.method( 2 ).then(function( Result ) {
    log( "Result: " + JSON.stringify( Result ));
});
```

---

Output:

Result: {"Property":1,"Result":[2]}
Result: {"Property":0,"Result":[2,1]}

---

Comment: `extend` doesn't make a deep copy of the object, so all your models share the same `Result` array.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!!!